# Why calling base class contructor is mandatory?

Tags: python, inheritance

I would like to know why in Python, a derived class has to call the constructor of its base class in order to inherit all instance attributes.

For example:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
   self.a = 0

class B(A):
   def __init__(self):
   super().__init__()   # this is mandatory in order to inherit A's instance attributes 
   self.b = 1

a = A()
b = B()
print(b.a)                # this gives an error it the line super().__init__() is omitted
```

However, in other programming languages, calling base class constructor is not necessary.

Comment: because unlike other languages, python class variables are both defined and inited in the constructor

Comment: The child class overrides `__init__()` instead of inheriting it from the parent, so it needs a way to say "go do all the stuff that my parent's `__init__()` would have done."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it's not *mandatory* that you call the superclass's `__init__` method. You only need to do that if you need its behavior in your subclass. If your subclass is doing something different, you can skip the call.

For example, if the base class does an expensive calculation, but a subclass is for a special case where a faster one could be used instead, you can skip the expensive call like this:

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.a = expensive_computation(x)

class NormalDerived(Base):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x) # Base.__init__ does the expensive computation for us
        self.b = something_else(x)

class SpecialCaseDerived(Base):
    def __init__(self, x):
        # don't call super here,  instead, do a different computation for "a" ourselves
        self.a = cheaper_computation(x)
        self.b = something_else(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other languages, instance variables in python are both defined and initialised in the constructor method.

More generaly instance variables can only be defined in methods not in the class definition. This is a feature of python in the way it is designed and implemented.

See for example: [Understanding class and instance variables in Python 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3)

So for your example if you want to **inherit** the instance variables you have to **call super constructor**, else re-define them again.